# Why jquery change method don't works well?

Tags: jquery, django

I have a problem with two checkbox, the problem is that I have two categories 
Venta and Renta

So if I check Venta or Renta or both the method works fine, but if I uncheck for example Renta the method don't work correctly, So I uncheck the two categories and the code works fine, but I don't understand Why or Where is my problem

This is my jquery code:

```
            $(".venta").change(function () {

                    if (this.checked) {

                         $(this).val('1');
                    Visualizar_Unidades(0,0,0);
                    }

                    else{

                        $(this).val('0');

                    Eliminar_Unidades();

                    }
            });

            $(".renta").change(function () {


               if (this.checked) {

                         $(this).val('1');
                    Visualizar_Unidades(0,0,0);
                    }

                    else{

                        $(this).val('0');

                    Eliminar_Unidades();

                    }

            });
```

The function Visualizar_Unidades:

```
function Visualizar_Unidades(dueño, m2, nueva)
        {
             var bandera=0;
            var venta=$(".venta").val();
            var renta=$(".renta").val();
             if(parseFloat(venta)==1 && parseFloat(renta)==1 )
            {
                bandera=0;

                alert(venta+renta);



            }
            else
            {
                if(parseFloat(venta)==1 && parseFloat(renta)==0 )
                {
                    bandera=2;


                }
                else
                {
                    if(parseFloat(venta)==0 && parseFloat(renta)==1 )
                    {
                        bandera=1;


                    }

                }
            }




                var extra=$(".inmueble").val();
                var min = $('#header_min').val().replace(/,/g, "");
                var max = $('#header_max').val().replace(/,/g, "");



            if (min == ""){
                min = 0;
            }
            if (max ==""){

                max=0;
            }

            if (extra==""){

                extra=0;

        }
            $.get(/JSON/+bandera+"&"+min+"&"+max+"&"+0, function (data) {

                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            if (item.tipo_venta==1){
                 icono = "{% static 'FrontEnd/images/punto_azul_sombreado.png' %}";  
            }
            if (item.tipo_venta==2){
                   icono = "{% static 'FrontEnd/images/punto_rojo.png' %}";         
            }

                    markers_dataV.push({
                        lat: item.latitud,
                        lng: item.longitud,

                        draggable: true,

                        icon: icono,
                        click: function (e) {

                            map.setZoom(15);
                            map.setCenter(item.latitud, item.longitud);

                            var id = item.id_unidad;
                            var tipo = item.id_tipo_unidad.tipo_vista

                           //llama a la funcion para llenar con informacion el modal
                            InfoModal(id, tipo);
                            //verificar qie tipo de modal abrira
                            var modal_mostrar = '';
                            if (parseFloat(tipo) == 1 )
                            {
                                modal_mostrar = 'Modal';
                            } 
                            else
                            {
                                modal_mostrar = 'Modal_casas';

                            }
                            $("#" + modal_mostrar).modal();
                        }
                    });


                });

                map.addMarkers(markers_dataV);

            });


        }
```

This is the function Eliminar_Unidades:

```
  function Eliminar_Unidades()
        {
            map.removeMarkers();
            markers_dataV.length = 0;
        }
```

Comment: Hi, please give more info, what VisualizarUnidades and Eliminar_Unidades should acomplish? What exacly is not working? (Im from Brazil, so i kinda know what both functions should do).

Comment: Cool, but can you say what this code should do, that's not happening? I'm prutty sure it's a simple thing.

Comment: I try to explain you,  when I check some Option Venta o Renta the function  Visualizar_Unidades returns successfully the data, and if I check both the same result, but If I have the two Checkox checked and I uncheck one checkbox the function Visualizar_Unidades don't work

Comment: I would sugest you something but Pejka already answered.

Comment: Yes but it don't work

Comment: Why don't you pass a parameter to "Eliminar_Unidades", removing only what should be removed? Why remove all of them? Isn't better for performance?

Comment: But how can I do that?

Comment: I'll give you a full answer (not as comment)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to display certain markers on a map based on which checkboxes are selected. Whenever you check a box, it calls Visualizar_Unidades, which adds the markers.
Based on what I see, calling Eliminar_Unidades just resets your whole map. Try calling Visualizar_Unidades instead, or call it inside Eliminar_Unidades like so:

```
function Eliminar_Unidades()
{
    map.removeMarkers();
    markers_dataV.length = 0;
    Visualizar_Unidades(0,0,0);
}
```

Comment: Yes thatis my problem, I try your answer but don't work.

Comment: Do you get any errors in your browser console? There may be something that throws an error, and you can use that to track down the issue. Also when in doubt, I personally use console.log(some_variable) liberally to check the value of everything, at every step, to make sure things go as planned.

Comment: any error bro, I don't understand why happends that problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution appears to be remove only the necessary marks, not all of them at once:

```
function Eliminar_Unidades(objeto)//exemple '.venta_unitys'
        {
            map.removeMarkers(objeto);//remove all objects with some class
            markers_dataV.length = 0;
        }
```